# Update matplotlib plot in PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, pyqt5

I have created a program which embeds a plot from matplotlib in PyQt5. The plotted data should change when pressing a button, but the plot will not refresh. The code is based on the code on the website pythonguis.com - "Plotting with Matplotlib" by Martin Fitzpatrick.

To create the project I use venv with following details:

- macOS
- python:     3.6
- PyQt5:      5.13.0
- matplotlib: 3.3.4

The connection between the button and the `update_plot` function works fine, but `self.canvas.draw()` seems to fail.
I am thankful for every reply!:)

```
import matplotlib
import random
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(fig)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Plot")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.update_plot)

        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.n_data = 50
        self.xdata = list(range(self.n_data))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(self.n_data)]

        self.update_plot()
        self.show()

    def update_plot(self):
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()  
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        self.canvas.draw()
        print("Plotted!")
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w   = Window()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I tested it on Windows and it is working fine! Clicking the button shifts the y values by 1, adding a random number to the right most for each click.

Comment: try add `self.canvas.repaint()`

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you! Now it works! I was just about trying a different release of PyQt, there seems to be some problems on macOS.